# Irreducible decomposition of algebraic set via a decomposition of the polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, algebraic-curves

I am trying to understand the proof of the following theorem:

Let $f \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and $f = \prod_{i=1}^{r} f_i^{n_i}$ be a decomposition of $f$ into irreducible factors. Then, $V(f) = \cup_i V(f_i)$ is the decomposition of $V(f)$ into irreducible components, and $I(V(f)) = (f_1...f_r)$.

Pf. (of second statement)

$I(V(f)) = I(\cup V(f_i)) = \cap_i I(V(f_i)) = \cap_i(f_i) = (f_1...f_r).$

I have trouble seeing why the second last equation holds. Please can you explain why that equation holds?

Comment: In general, $I(V(\mathfrak{a}))=\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}$ for any ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. (This is Hilbert's Nullstellensatz.) Since $f_i$ is irreducible, $(f_i)$ is prime so $\sqrt{(f_i)}=(f_i)$.

Comment: Thanks, @WLOG. One more question: why does $f_i$ irreducible imply $(f_i)$ prime? I thought usually you have an implication in the other way, provided you're in a domain.

Comment: The general result that we use here is that if a ring $R$ is a UFD, then $R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is also a UFD. With unique factorizations, it is straightforward to show that irreducible elements are the same as prime elements.

Comment: Thanks, maybe you should post this as an answer @WLOG